# webshot2::webshot is trimming the right side off of a huxtable in R

Tags: r, huxtable, webshot

I am trying to convert an html table created in R via the `huxtable` package to a png file using `webshot2::webshot`. Unfortunately, the very right side of the output seems to get trimmed off and I can't figure out how to fix this generically.

I don't want to manually tweak the `cliprect` parameter because I'll need to do this for many tables and its not scalable if its not generic. However, it is possible to achieve it with this parameter so I wonder why its failing with the other workflow.

Here's an example illustrating the problem:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(huxtable)
set.seed(1337)

data <- matrix(rnorm(25), 35, 10)
my_hux <- as_hux(data) %>%
  set_outer_borders(0.4) %>%
  map_background_color(by_rows("grey95", "white")) %>%
  map_text_color(by_quantiles(c(0.1, 0.9), c("red", "black", "green3")))

quick_html(my_hux, file = "ahuxtable.html", open = FALSE)

webshot2::webshot(url = "ahuxtable.html", file = "ahuxtable.png",
                  zoom = 5, selector = "table")
```

I tried this with `webshot::webshot`, however the `webshot` package seems to be `webshot2`'s predecessor so I'd prefer a `webshot2` solution if there is one.

Comment: Just out of interest can you tell me why you want to do this?

Comment: I am producing HTML reports via RMarkdown, which incorporate huxtables. For the primary HTML everything works fine. A secondary output are PowerPoint slides. I tried doing this with RMarkdown too, however, the tables in the resultsing pptx get a little garbled stylewise. That is, column widths etc change and a lot of manual post-processing becomes necessary. Thus I have opted to produce static png versions of the huxtables which are then linked in the pptx. The static version looks exactly like in the HTML report. Currently I have a working `webshot` solution.